# What am I doing wrong on passing data through protocol

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I'm trying to pass data between viewControllers, but something seems wrong.

The first viewController I want to set the "Bool" to the protocol function to be able to recover in the other screen. What am I doing wrong, I always used protocols but at this time I got in trouble.

That's how I'm doing that:

```
//
//  ComboBoxNode.swift
//

import Foundation
import SWXMLHash


protocol ComboBoxNodeDelegate {
    func getCustomOption(data:Bool)
}

class ComboBoxNode: FormControlNode, IFormControlDataSource {


    var listType: String?
    var dataSource: String?
    var dataSourceValue: String?
    var dataSourceText: String?
    var hasCustomOption:Bool?
    var customOptionText: String?
    var ctrlDataSourceType: String?
    var parameters = [ParameterNode]()
    var staticList: FormControlStaticListNode?

    var delegate:ComboBoxNodeDelegate?

    override init(indexer: XMLIndexer) {
        super.init(indexer: indexer)

        guard let element = indexer.element else {
            preconditionFailure("Error")
        }


        let isCustomOption = element.bool(by: .hasCustomOption) ?? hasCustomOption

        if isCustomOption == true {
            self.delegate?.getCustomOption(data: hasCustomOption!)
        }


        self.readFormControlDataSource(indexer: indexer)
    }

    override func accept<T, E: IViewVisitor>(visitor: E) -> T where E.T == T {
        return visitor.visit(node: self)
    }
}
```

That's how I'm trying to recover on next screen:

```
//  FormPickerViewDelegate.swift

import Foundation
import ViewLib
import RxSwift

class FormPickerViewDelegate: NSObject {

    var items = Variable([(value: AnyHashable, text: String)]()) {
        didSet {
            PickerNodeDelegate = self
            self.setDefaultValues()
        }
    }

    private var controlViewModel: FormControlViewModel
    private var customText:Bool?

    private var PickerNodeDelegate:ComboBoxNodeDelegate?

    init(controlViewModel: FormControlViewModel) {
        self.controlViewModel = controlViewModel
    }

    func getItemByValue(_ value: Any) -> (AnyHashable, String)? {

        if value is AnyHashable {
            let found = items.value.filter {$0.value == value as! AnyHashable}
            if found.count >= 1 {
                return found[0]
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}


extension FormPickerViewDelegate:ComboBoxNodeDelegate {
    func getCustomOption(data: Bool) {
        customText = data
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are just referencing `PickerNodeDelegate` to itself, and your `FormPickerViewDelegate` class is not conforming to `ComboBoxNodeDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Can you suggest me where I should edit?

Comment: There is no way that the `delegate` property in `ComboBoxNode` can have a value in `init` - since the delegate isn't set in `init` and you can't reference the object from some other place until `init` is complete.  In `FormPickerViewDelegate` you are setting its `PickerNodeDelegate` to itself and never invoking the delegate's function anyway.

Comment: If you just want to pass a property from one screen to the next, you probably don't need a delegation pattern.  I can't really tell you what to change though because the relationship between the two classes shown isn't clear.

Comment: What If I use a static var to try to persist?

Comment: You shouldn't need a static var.   Can you explain how `ComboBoxNode` and `FormPickerViewDelegate` relate to each other?  Which one holds a reference to the other?

Comment: Basically ComboBoxNode receives a XML which contains all “details” to build the PickerView, such as dataSource, required, visible options etc. So, PickerNodeDelegate contains default pickerview methods and delegates to be able to be filled with data from ComboBoxNode (XML)

Comment: However, the purpose for this question is because I receive a property on my ComboNode that’s called “hasCustomOption” sometimes it comes as true or false. I gotta store this property and observe its state, because if it’s comes as true my delegates should do a specific thing. I don’t know if you understood well

Comment: add delegate when you present and push or if not present add on override init{} . (delegate = self)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `PickerNodeDelegate = self` in `didSet {}` closure

```
   var items = Variable([(value: AnyHashable, text: String)]()) {
        didSet {
            PickerNodeDelegate = self
            self.setDefaultValues()
        }
    }
```

Assign it in your init() function instead

```
    init(controlViewModel: FormControlViewModel) {
        self.controlViewModel = controlViewModel
        PickerNodeDelegate = self
    }
```

Note, your should declare your delegate to be `weak` also, since it's a delegate, your protocol should conform to be a class type in order to be weakified.

```
protocol ComboBoxNodeDelegate: class
...
weak var delegate: ComboBoxNodeDelegate?
```

Comment: You won't be able to declare `delegate` as `weak` unless you make the protocol class-bound.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, hope it helps!

```
protocol ComboBoxNodeDelegate {
    func getCustomOption(data:Bool) -> String 
}

class ViewOne:ComboBoxNodeDelegate {
    var foo:Bool = false
    var bar:String = "it works!"

    /** Return: String */
    func getCustomOption(data:Bool) -> String { //conform here to protocol
          // do whatever you wanna do here ...example
          self.foo = data // you can set
          return bar // even return what you want

    }

    //initialize
    func initalizeViewTwo() {
         let v2 = ViewTwo()
         v2.delegate = self //since `self` conforms to the ComboBoxNodeDelegate protcol you are allowed to set
    }


}

class ViewTwo { 
    var delegate:ComboBoxNodeDelegate?

    func getCustomOption_forV1() {
        let view2_foo = delegate.getCustomOption(data:true)
        print(view2_foo) // should print "it works!"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, so if you want ViewTwo to receive some data, you can do it like so. ^^^ ( I will update the code)

Answer (score -1):

All parameters passed around in Swift are constants -- so you cannot change them.

If you want to change them in a function, you must declare your protocol to pass by reference with `inout`:

```
protocol ComboBoxNodeDelegate {
    func getCustomOption(data: inout Bool)
}
```

Note: you cannot pass a constant (let) to this function. It must be a variable -- which I see you are doing!